# Is it possible in SwiftUI to only allow one onTapGesture input at a time?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to Swift so please excuse my ignorance on this topic. I'm trying to write a simple Tic Tac Toe game as a personal project to learn Swift but I keep running into an issue where if the user were to hit multiple spaces at exactly the same time, the game would place the "X" in both spots.

I have it set so that once a space is tapped by the user, a var named "playerTurn" toggles to false to prevent the user from tapping another spot until after the AI has done its turn, at which point, it toggles playerTurn back to true. The toggle happens within the "updateBlock()" func. Every time the user taps on a space, an if statement checks whether it's the player's turn or not.

The problem is that if the user taps on two or more spaces as just the right time, the function in both spaces will execute because it did not have enough time to toggle playerTurn to false. I have a piece of the code below. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I just can't seem to figure out how to get it to work the way I need. Any assistance is much appreciated!

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    Image(iconArray[blockValue[0]])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .scaleEffect(0.9)
        .onTapGesture {
            if playerTurn == true && zeroBlocksExist[0] == true {
                // Ensure that it is the player's turn and that the space is vacant before updating the space with the new value
                updateBlock(blockPosition: 0)
            }
        }
    Image(iconArray[blockValue[1]])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .scaleEffect(0.9)
        .onTapGesture {
            if playerTurn == true && zeroBlocksExist[1] == true {
                // Ensure that it is the player's turn and that the space is vacant before updating the space with the new value
                updateBlock(blockPosition: 1)
            }
        }
    Image(iconArray[blockValue[2]])
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .scaleEffect(0.9)
        .onTapGesture {
            if playerTurn == true && zeroBlocksExist[2] == true {
                // Ensure that it is the player's turn and that the space is vacant before updating the space with the new value
                updateBlock(blockPosition: 2)
            }
        }
    Spacer()
}

// updateBlock function 

func updateBlock(blockPosition: Int) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if movesCount < 9 {
                if playerTurn == true {
                    playerTurn.toggle() // Disable player turn
                    titleText = "CPU's turn"
                    restartButtonState.toggle() // Disable the restart button until after the CPU does its turn
                    blockValue[blockPosition] = 1 // Put the X icon in the requested space
                    if allowSounds {
                        playAudio(soundName: "pop-1", soundExt: "mp3") // Play the pop sound effect
                    }
                    checkVacantBlocks() // Check vacant blocks and update the array
                } else if playerTurn == false {
                    blockValue[blockPosition] = 2 // Put the O icon
                    playerTurn.toggle()
                    titleText = "Your turn"
                    restartButtonState.toggle() // Enable the restart button
                    checkVacantBlocks()
                }
                movesCount += 1
                print("Moves made: ", String(movesCount))
            } else if movesCount >= 9 {
                print("Game board full!")
                checkWinnings()
            }
            return
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Unless you're using something like `DispatchQueue` inside your `updateBlock`, it doesn't seem like this should be possible. I'm assuming that inside it, you change `playerTurn` to false at some point. Because UI code runs on a single main thread, there shouldn't be a scenario in which both taps can read `playerTurn` as `true` and execute their code in tandem, since it would occur on the same thread. But, again, this is assuming that you aren't dispatching out during `updateBlock`

Comment: @jnpdx I'm using DispatchQueue.global().async in the updateBlock() func so that it can update the UI. If it's not there, the UI won't update at all. And yes, the very first thing in the updateBlock function is to toggle the playerTurn to false if it finds that it is currently set to true.

Comment: You must have two dispatch calls. Anything that gets called as a result of `onTapGesture` would *already* be on the main thread. But, this confirms that you have not included enough code in our example to diagnose this issue. You must have introduced a race condition by moving between threads, none of which is shown in the code that you've given.

Comment: @jnpdx I just updated the code with the function that gets called when the user taps the space. After the checkVacantBlocks func executes, it runs another func called checkWinnings which will re-execute the updateBlocks func with the AI's selected space given the game did not already end.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the DispatchQueue block and using it *only* when you need to do something computationally expensive. No reason to do any of the code that you have listed so far inside a different queue -- keep it easy and stay on the main thread and inside the same run loop.

Comment: @jnpdx I'll give it a try. Thank you for your help!